# Working with Xstream, clarification needed

Tags: java, classpath, xstream

Consider a simple Xsctream example to create JSON out of the Bean:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
bean.addNames("John", "Doe");
bean.addNames("Jane", "Doe");

XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());    
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);

System.out.println(xstream.toXML(bean));
```

results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jettison/mapped/Configuration
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver.<init>(JettisonMappedXmlDriver.java:55)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Note that **libraries are imported** as they should be

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver;
```

And proper **jars are included**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need jettison.jar from codehaus 
[click this link](http://jettison.codehaus.org/)

Comment: I have jettison.jar and it's in my build path but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Check if you are referencing the correct jar and it is getting loaded